# Godot - Check if Slider is being hovered over

Tags: user-interface, hover, slider, godot

I want to be able to hide the slider if it isn't being hovered over. Has_focus() only works if it was being clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sliders, you should be able to use the mouse_enter() signal to handle "hovering." And then mouse_exit() when the cursor leaves the slider. But make sure that "Ignore Mouse" is not checked on the slider properties.

http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html?highlight=mouse_enter